# How to query nested Array type of a json file using Spark?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

How can I query a nested Array type using joins using Spark dataset?

Currently I'm exploding the Array type and doing join on the dataset where I need  to remove the matched data. But is there a way wherein I can directly query it without exploding.

```
{
  "id": 525,
  "arrayRecords": [
    {
      "field1": 525,
      "field2": 0
    },
    {
      "field1": 537,
      "field2": 1
    }
  ]
}
```

The code

```
val df = sqlContext.read.json("jsonfile")
val someDF = Seq(("1"),("525"),("3")).toDF("FIELDIDS")
val withSRCRec =df.select($"*",explode($"arrayRecords")as("exploded_arrayRecords"))
val fieldIdMatchedDF= withSRCRec.as("table1").join(someDF.as("table2"),$"table1.exploded_arrayRecords.field1"===$"table2.FIELDIDS").select($"table1.exploded_arrayRecords.field1")

val finalDf = df.as("table1").join(fieldIdMatchedDF.as("table2"),$"table1.id"===$"table2.id","leftanti")
```

Id records having fieldIds need to be removed

Comment: Do you want to filter out IDs in `field1` only? How many elements could there be in  the dataframe with `FIELDIDS`?

Answer (score 0):

You could use `array_except` instead:

> **array_except(col1: Column, col2: Column): Column** Returns an array of the elements in the first array but not in the second array, without duplicates. The order of elements in the result is not determined

A solution could be as follows:

```
val input = spark.read.option("multiLine", true).json("input.json")
scala> input.show(false)
+--------------------+---+
|arrayRecords        |id |
+--------------------+---+
|[[525, 0], [537, 1]]|525|
+--------------------+---+

// Since field1 is of type int, let's convert the ids to ints
// You could do this in Scala directly or in Spark SQL's select
val fieldIds = Seq("1", "525", "3").toDF("FIELDIDS").select($"FIELDIDS" cast "int")

// Collect the ids for array_except
val ids = fieldIds.select(collect_set("FIELDIDS") as "ids")

// The trick is to crossJoin (it is cheap given 1-row ids dataset)
val solution = input
  .crossJoin(ids)
  .select(array_except($"arrayRecords.field1", $"ids") as "unmatched")
scala> solution.show
+---------+
|unmatched|
+---------+
|    [537]|
+---------+
```

Answer (score -1):

You can register a temporary table based on your dataset and query it with SQL. It would be something like this:

```
someDs.registerTempTable("sometable");
sql("SELECT array['field'] FROM sometable");
```